# jsp:useBean doesn't get a property value from a bean object

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i'm trying to get a property value from a bean object inside jsp using standard actions,the initial html form go to a servlet which sets a value inside the desired property,sets the attribute inside the request object and then forwards it to the jsp page, the jsp gets the value from the property by using standard actions but it gets null!:

the bean object:

```
public class dog {
private String bread;
public String getBread() {
    return bread;
}

 public void setBread(String bread) {
    this.bread = bread;
}

 }
```

the servlet:

```
        dog d=new dog();
        d.setBread("Kizer");
        request.setAttribute("bread", d);
        RequestDispatcher view=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
```

the JSP (index):

```
 < id="person" class="com.example.model.dog" scope="request" />
```

Person created by servlet: `<jsp:getProperty name="person" property="bread" />`

why it returns null ?

Comment: Try using  ${bread.bread}  in your JSP.

Comment: i want to retreive the value using standard actions!

Comment: The `<jsp:useBean>` is **absolutely not** a "standard action" when using a servlet as MVC controller. Remove it altogether and just use `${bread.bread}`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info By the way, it's to be spelled ["breed"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/breed), not ["bread"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bread).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSP use

```
<jsp:useBean id="bread" class="com.example.model.dog" scope="request" />
<jsp:getProperty name="bread" property="bread" />
```

Comment: Explanation: it returned `null` because you were creating a completely new instance of dog with name `person` instead of reusing the one set by servlet with name `bread`. So you need to fix the `id` to point the same name as set by servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Using bean id atrribute is the same as bean object.